# Caring for Ficus Starlight plant

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, ficus

I have a Ficus Starlight with green and yellow leaves. The size of the leaves are small, not very big. Is this plant require same care as weeping fig?

What is the correct soil mix for this plant and light requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fig trees of all kinds except the really tall ones prefer bright but indirect light. Since your Starlight is variegated it will grow better in really good light since it shows less green to the light than other fully green types. Put it out on the deck in a protected spot on bright, warm cloudy days but hide it from direct sun.

For soil you want something that will drain sharply, say with a good sand content. Figs have lustrous, water-retaining leaves. Try bending a leaf and watch it snap back straight when you let it go. Unlike other thin leaves which transpire easily figs are slow to need water. If the leaves are stiff and healthy they will not call for water from the roots, so if you water when they don't need it the roots will sit in water. This is why you need soil that if over-watered will let it drain away quickly. Let the soil go quite dry before watering, and when adding water do so just a little at a time.

If your plant looks well and healthy right now, weigh it, pot and all, and note that measurement. After a week weigh again and if it is the same weight you know you don't need to water it at all. When you see a sharp drop in weight that is not explained, then add water to bring it back to the originally noted weight.

Fertilize only when you see it trying to produce new leaves, and then only give half the recommended amount. To track changes in growth it can be helpful to mark a small branch by putting a twist tie around it (so you can find it again easily) and take a photo of that branch. Then when new growth appears later you can compare and the difference will be clear.

Comment: in terms of soil mix  I would use a high proportion of organic metrial like sun dry cow manure and sand with garden soil. (5 parts garden soil + 3 parts dry cow manure or compost + 2 parts agricultural sand )

Comment: @seedelicious That's what I used.

Comment: I saw some fig tress planted in ground in sun and they were doing fine. Mine is kinda turning its leave yellow. I think overwatering.

Comment: great minds think alike :)    make sure it's not nutrition lockout from wrong soil ph

Comment: oh! I simply added little bit of cow manure and some peat moss. How do I check that? @seedelicious

Comment: basically you can use soil ph testing kits

Comment: peat moss and manure would defo change the ph of the soil